# Group by clientId and date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

[image: Table]

I want to do groupBy date and by specific client where `IsDeleted = 0`.

More precisely, I want to do this:

[image: Result]

Data in this screenshot doesn't reflect data in the table.

So, for example, client Anne Marie is ClientId = 12 in my database.

I need to group by for each month and then another group by? I mean, I can have multiple records in one month..

I hope I posted clear question, if not, please write to put more details on.

Update:

I need something like this:

```
select 
    Convert([date], [Date]) as [Date], 
    TotalAttendants as Total,
    FemaleAttendants as Women, 
    MaleAttendants
from
    dbo.Events
where 
    EventTypeId = 1 
    and IsDeleted = 0
group by 
    Convert([date], date)
order by 
    Convert([date], date)
```

Only I need to wrap those dates into Months (T-SQL or something similar).

At the, end I need to rewrite this query to linq for C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, from your example picture of desired output, you just need to use the `sum` aggregate function and group by the `date` in each case, however it's not clear what you mean by "another group by", so clarify if you need to.

```
select concat(Left(DateName(month,[date]),3), ' ', Year([date])), 
    sum(TotalAttendants) as Total,
    Sum(FemaleAttemdants) as Women,
    Sum(MaleAttendants) as Men
from table
where IsDeleted=0
group by concat(Left(DateName(month,[date]),3), ' ', Year([date]))
```

Comment: it works, just I need date to be presented like: [January, February, March..] to group by those dates into one month per se

Comment: @Stefan0309 I've made an edit to get the month and year only.

Comment: can you write it to an linq lambda expression? I will accept your answer. thanks

Comment: @Stefan0309 you didn't tag c# or indicate that in your question at all - sorry I don't use `linq`